# How to set UICollectionView width programmatically

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to set the width of an UICollectionView programmatically. I have tried to modify collectionView.frame and .bounds without success.

```
class CenterCellCollectionViewFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
 override func targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset(proposedContentOffset: CGPoint, withScrollingVelocity velocity: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
   if let cv = self.collectionView {
     let cvBounds = cv.bounds
     let width = cvBounds.size.width //this is always 600, it should be 320
   }
 }
 return super.targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset(proposedContentOffset)
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
 @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
 override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   collectionView.frame = CGRectMake(collectionView.frame.origin.x, collectionView.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.width, collectionView.frame.height)
   collectionView.bounds = CGRectMake(collectionView.bounds.origin.x, collectionView.bounds.origin.y, self.view.frame.width, collectionView.bounds.height)
   let width = collectionView.bounds.width //this is 320
   collectionView.reloadData()
 }
}
```

[Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAsVq.png)

Comment: Changing frame should work. Please add your code...?

Comment: Seems like your UICollectionView might use NSLayoutConstraints for positioning. Check this first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `NSLayoutConstraint`s:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/

The reason you are getting an incorrect width is because you are setting it in `viewDidLoad()`. `self.view` has not been laid out at this point in the lifecycle. `viewWillLayoutSubviews()` is the lifecycle method you want to use, as it is called after `self.view` has been laid out and allows you to manually adjust any subview's (your `UICollectionView`) layout.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `self.view.frame.width` when building your `Rect`, which means you are getting the `width` of your `ViewController`'s view. This `ViewController` is probably taking the full screen, which means 320 pixels on an iPhone 4 or iPhone 5.